# Params error undefine

Tags: android, parameters

The main activity declares the variable type, username and password

```
    UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);

    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
```

then BackgroundWorker.java will execute and use the values type, username and password by declaring params[value]...

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String[] voids) {
    String type = this.params[0];

    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/ITSP/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String username = this.params[1];
            String password = this.params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("")
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```

But why does "params[0]" is undefined in this code? I'm using android studio version 3.1.3. Should I replace params? what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

try  this way to get params value

```
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(String[] voids) {
    String type = voids[0];

    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/ITSP/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String username = voids[1];
            String password =voids[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("")
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```